# Windowsパワーシェルで起動時に作業ディレクトリを与える事は可能でしょうか？

Tags: windows, powershell

表題の件でございますが、コマンドプロンプト上でpowershellと入力するとパワーシェルが立ち上がります。

この時作業ディレクトリはコマンドプロンプト上での作業ディレクトリが引き継がれますが、起動時に任意の作業ディレクトリを起動オプションで与える事は可能でしょうか？

可能であればご教示いただけますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

※Windows10標準のパワーシェルを使用しております。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトからでないことはわかりますが、どのように起動する時の質問でしょうか？ ちなみにファイルエクスプローラーの`File`メニューから起動した場合、エクスプローラーが開いているディレクトリで起動します。

Comment: すみませんでした。　VB.NETでのProcessクラスのStartinfoで引数として与えられればと考えています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectoryプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.100).aspx)を設定してください。併せて[ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecuteプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.100).aspx)をfalseに設定する必要があります。
`WorkingDirectory`プロパティがコマンドプロンプトの作業ディレクトリです。

Comment: Sayuriさま、回答ありがとうございます。早速確認してみます。

Comment: UseShellExecute の値によって実行可能ファイルの検索パスは変化しますが、UseShellExecute がtrueでも WorkingDirectory は作業ディレクトリの指定として機能するのではないでしょうか。